# Partially applying type parameters

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

I'm desperately trying to solve the following:

```
trait Access[Res[_]] { def access[C]: Res[C] }

trait CList[C1, A] extends Access[CList[_, A]] // ?!

def test[C1, C2, A](c: CList[C1, A]): CList[C2, A] = c.access[C2]
```

scalac just says: `"error: illegal cyclic reference involving trait CList"`. how can I make this compile?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might be interested in type lambdas. The partial application you used in your answer is actually [implemented in scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/PartialApplys.scala).
As the code tends to get less readable though, they started using type lambdas instead. The type in question could be written as

```
({type λ[α] = CList[α,A]})#λ
```

This works by creating a type projection on a parameterized type `λ` inside a structural type thus capturing the outer type parameter (in this case `A`).

The other problem concerning variance described in your answer could be solved by making the `Res` parameter in `Access` covariant.

After these changes your code should look like this:

```
trait Access[+Res[_]] { def access[C] : Res[C]}

trait CList[C, +A] extends Access[({type λ[α] = CList[α,A]})#λ]
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks a bit better. Also since in my real case the type parameters of CList had upper bounds, having a dedicated trait Partial2 was not really helpful (i would need to add types parameters for the bounds etc.)

Comment: Also if type lambdas are used often in your code,  consider the following compiler plugin:
https://github.com/non/kind-projector

Answer (score 3):

Just to update things 
add this compiler plugin to your **sbt** for **kind projection** and you'll get a nice syntax using **`?`**. 
 This removes the type projection boilerplate which looks messy!
So you can write stuff like **`Either[String, ?]`**

**addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" %% "kind-projector" % "0.9.7")**

it's implemented with the same old type projection underneath

You can also find it here: 
https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2016/12/05/type-lambdas.html

Answer (score 2):

googling for "partial type application" i found this solution posted by James Iry on the scala debate list ( http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Partial-type-inference-td2007311.html ; adapted so the arg order is changed):

```
type Partial2[T[_,_], B] = {
   type Apply[A] = T[A,B]
}
trait CList[C1, A] extends Access[Partial2[CList, A]#Apply]
```

cheese louise, is this really the only way to do that in scala in 2011 ?!!

**EDIT:**

This fails with covariance in `A` :,-(

```
trait Access[Res[_]] { def access[C]: Res[C] }

type Partial2[T[_,_], B] = {
  type Apply[A] = T[A,B]
}
trait CList[C1, +A] extends Access[Partial2[CList, A]#Apply]

"covariant type A occurs in invariant position"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but anyway:

```
trait AnyAccess {
  type Res[X]
  def access[Z]: Res[Z]
}

trait AnyCList extends AnyAccess { me =>
  type C
  type A
  // this could be a subtype bound instead, if needed
  type Res[X] = AnyCList { type C = X; type A = me.A }
}
case object AnyCList {
  type of[C0, +A0] = AnyCList { type C = C0; type A <: A0 }
}

case object buh {

  def test[C1, C2, A](c: AnyCList.of[C1, A]): AnyCList.of[C2, A] = c.access[C2]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that worked for me to "partially apply type parameters":

I had a function like

```
def foo[A, B, C, D, E](...)
```

Such that I needed to hint only one type parameter for the compiler to infer the rest. This worked for me:

```
object InferType {
  type InferType[A] = Option[A]
  def apply[A]: Option[A] = None
}
```

Update foo to take an additional parameter of type InferType:

```
// t parameter is unused in implementation but
// is used by compiler to infer other type parameters
def foo[A, B, C, D, E](..., t: InferType[D])
```

Usage:

```
foo(..., InferType[ConcreteD])
```