# How To Convert the Builder Pattern to a Functional Implementation?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, builder, grpc-java

The `grpc-java` library is a good example of a library that utilizes the common builder pattern for creating objects with particular properties:

```
val sslContext = ???

val nettyChannel : NettyChannel = 
  NettyChannelBuilder
    .forAddress(hostIp, hostPort)
    .useTransportSecurity()
    .sslContext(sslContext) 
    .build
```

**Given a library that uses this pattern how can it be wrapt so that a proper functional API can be made available?**  I would imagine a monad is the appropriate tool to use.

A basic first attempt would look like:

```
val updateBuilder : (NettyChannelBuilder => Unit) => NettyChannelBuilder => NettyChannelBuilder = 
  updateFunc => builder => {
    updateFunc(builder)
    builder
  } 

val addTransportSecurity : NettyChannelBuilder => Unit = 
  (_ : NettyChannelBuilder).useTransportSecurity()

val addSslContext : NettyChannelBuilder => Unit = 
  builder => {
    val sslContext = ???
    builder sslContext sslContext
  }
```

Although this method is verbose it would at least allow for composition:

```
 val builderPipeline : NettyChannelBuilder => NettyChannelBuilder =
   updateBuilder(addTransportSecurity) andThen updateBuilder(addSslContext)

 val nettyChannel = 
   builderPipeline(NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(hostIp, hostPort)).build
```

One constraint: no using `scalaz`, `cats`, or some other 3rd party library.  Only scala language "stuff".

Note: grpc is just an example use case, not the primary point of the question...

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: if, as you say, _I would imagine a monad is the appropriate tool to use._ Why not employ a canonical implementation of them?

Comment: @Yaneeve I believe the "canonical implementation of them" is what I'm asking for in the question.  "I would imagine" that space travel is necessary to get to Mars, but I don't know how to implement it...

Comment: How about the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42056126/101715)?

Comment: @Yaneeve Thank you for the reference.  The sticking point is that `map` takes in an `A => B` function whereas builders use `A => Unit`.  Perhaps the solution involves `Monad` along with the `updateBuilder` function from my question, but I am not sure.  Hence the stack question...

Comment: In FP, you generally do not mutate objects in place, but return new ones. This means that the `NettyChannelBuilder => Unit` needs to become `NettyChannelBuilder => NettyChannelBuilder` when the output of the function is the new instance of the builder with the new arguments applied.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I totally agree with "do not mutate objects in place".  My question is: given a library that you don't have control of, which does mutate in place, how can that be wrapped/abstracted so that a functional application can stay functional...

Comment: Oh no, FP is falling into the C++ fate: wrapperism.

Comment: I made an example:  https://repl.it/@djangofan/FunctionalBuilderjava

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Basic approach

If all the methods in the interface of the builder (except maybe `build` itself) just mutate the builder instance and return `this`, then they can be abstracted as `Builder => Unit` functions. This is true for `NettyChannelBuilder`, if I'm not mistaken. What you want to do in this case is to combine a bunch of those `Builder => Unit` into a single `Builder => Unit`, which runs the original ones consecutively.

Here is a direct implementation of this idea for `NettyChannelBuilder`:

```
object Builder {
  type Input = NettyChannelBuilder
  type Output = ManagedChannel

  case class Op(run: Input => Unit) {

    def and(next: Op): Op = Op { in =>
      this.run(in)
      next.run(in)
    }

    def runOn(in: Input): Output = {
      run(in)
      in.build()
    }
  }

  // combine several ops into one
  def combine(ops: Op*): Op = Op(in => ops.foreach(_.run(in)))

  // wrap methods from the builder interface

  val addTransportSecurity: Op = Op(_.useTransportSecurity())

  def addSslContext(sslContext: SslContext): Op = Op(_.sslContext(sslContext))

}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
val builderPipeline: Builder.Op =
  Builder.addTransportSecurity and
  Builder.addSslContext(???)

builderPipeline runOn NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 80)
```

### Reader Monad

It's also possible to use the Reader monad here. Reader monad allows combining two functions `Context => A` and `A => Context => B` into `Context => B`.  Of course every function you want to combine here is just `Context => Unit`, where the `Context` is `NettyChannelBuilder`. But the `build` method is `NettyChannelBuilder => ManagedChannel`, and we can add it into the pipeline with this approach.

Here is an implementation without any third-party libraries:

```
object MonadicBuilder {
  type Context = NettyChannelBuilder

  case class Op[Result](run: Context => Result) {
    def map[Final](f: Result => Final): Op[Final] =
      Op { ctx =>
        f(run(ctx))
      }

    def flatMap[Final](f: Result => Op[Final]): Op[Final] =
      Op { ctx =>
        f(run(ctx)).run(ctx)
      }
  }

  val addTransportSecurity: Op[Unit] = Op(_.useTransportSecurity())

  def addSslContext(sslContext: SslContext): Op[Unit] = Op(_.sslContext(sslContext))

  val build: Op[ManagedChannel] = Op(_.build())
}
```

It's convenient to use it with the for-comprehension syntax:

```
val pipeline = for {
  _ <- MonadicBuilder.addTransportSecurity
  sslContext = ???
  _ <- MonadicBuilder.addSslContext(sslContext)
  result <- MonadicBuilder.build
} yield result

val channel = pipeline run NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 80)
```

This approach can be useful in more complex scenarios, when some of the methods return other variables, which should be used in later steps. But for `NettyChannelBuilder` where most functions are just `Context => Unit`, it only adds unnecessary boilerplate in my opinion.

As for other monads, the main purpose of State is to track changes to a reference to an object, and it's useful because that object is normally immutable. For a mutable object Reader works just fine.

Free monad is used in similar scenarios as well, but it adds much more boilerplate, and its usual usage scenario is when you want to build an abstract syntax tree object with some actions/commands and then execute it with different interpreters.

### Generic builder

It's quite simple to adapt the previous two approaches to support any builder or mutable class in general. Though without creating separate wrappers for mutating methods, the boilerplate for using it grows quite a bit. For example, with the monadic builder approach:

```
class GenericBuilder[Context] {
  case class Op[Result](run: Context => Result) {
    def map[Final](f: Result => Final): Op[Final] =
      Op { ctx =>
        f(run(ctx))
      }

    def flatMap[Final](f: Result => Op[Final]): Op[Final] =
      Op { ctx =>
        f(run(ctx)).run(ctx)
      }
  }

  def apply[Result](run: Context => Result) = Op(run)

  def result: Op[Context] = Op(identity)
}
```

Using it:

```
class Person {
  var name: String = _
  var age: Int = _
  var jobExperience: Int = _

  def getYearsAsAnAdult: Int = (age - 18) max 0

  override def toString = s"Person($name, $age, $jobExperience)"
}

val build = new GenericBuilder[Person]

val builder = for {
  _ <- build(_.name = "John")
  _ <- build(_.age = 36)
  adultFor <- build(_.getYearsAsAnAdult)
  _ <- build(_.jobExperience = adultFor)
  result <- build.result
} yield result

// prints: Person(John, 36, 18) 
println(builder.run(new Person))
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that we said no `cats et al.` but I decided to post this up, first, in all honesty as an exercise for myself and second, since in essence these libraries simply aggregate "common" *typed functional* constructs and patterns.

After all, would you ever consider writing an HTTP server from vanilla Java/Scala or would you grab a battle tested one off the shelf? (sorry for the evangelism)

Regardless, you could replace their heavyweight implementation with a homegrown one of your own, if you really wanted.

I will present below, two schemes that came to mind, the first using the `Reader` *monad*, the second using the `State` *monad*. I personally find the first approach a bit more clunky than the second, but they are both not too pretty on the eye. I guess that a more experienced practitioner could do a better job at it than I.

Before that, I find the following rather interesting: [Semicolons vs Monads](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/1a241955b041283a9009)

---

The code:

I defined the Java Bean:

```
public class Bean {

    private int x;
    private String y;

    public Bean(int x, String y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bean{" +
                "x=" + x +
                ", y='" + y + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and the builder:

```
public final class BeanBuilder {
    private int x;
    private String y;

    private BeanBuilder() {
    }

    public static BeanBuilder aBean() {
        return new BeanBuilder();
    }

    public BeanBuilder withX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
        return this;
    }

    public BeanBuilder withY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
        return this;
    }

    public Bean build() {
        return new Bean(x, y);
    }
}
```

Now for the scala code:

```
import cats.Id
import cats.data.{Reader, State}

object Boot extends App {

  val r: Reader[Unit, Bean] = for {
    i <- Reader({ _: Unit => BeanBuilder.aBean() })
    n <- Reader({ _: Unit => i.withX(12) })
    b <- Reader({ _: Unit => n.build() })
    _ <- Reader({ _: Unit => println(b) })
  } yield b

  private val run: Unit => Id[Bean] = r.run
  println("will come before the value of the bean")
  run()


  val state: State[BeanBuilder, Bean] = for {
    _ <- State[BeanBuilder, BeanBuilder]({ b: BeanBuilder => (b, b.withX(13)) })
    _ <- State[BeanBuilder, BeanBuilder]({ b: BeanBuilder => (b, b.withY("look at me")) })
    bean <- State[BeanBuilder, Bean]({ b: BeanBuilder => (b, b.build()) })
    _ <- State.pure(println(bean))
  } yield bean

  println("will also come before the value of the bean")
  state.runA(BeanBuilder.aBean()).value
}
```

The output, due to the lazy nature of the evaluation of these monads is:

```
will come before the value of the bean
Bean{x=12, y='null'}
will also come before the value of the bean
Bean{x=13, y='look at me'}
```

Comment: Wow, this is a treatise in how FP makes things worse. Look at the lopsided absurdity of this: an object with 2 properties that go into a constructor and then reams of unreadable nonsense to build it. Perfect. Sorry, but this does not help. There is no Builder here. I could go on, the use of a for comprehension for Builder is by definition bad. The sequence of operations (how the thing is built) is supposed to be an interface that the Director uses.

Comment: That is why I said _typed_ functional [programming]. **You don't need types for FP.** Since the OP mentioned _Monads_ Both `Reader` and `State` jumped to mind. Either which way, the OP also mentioned no 3rd party libs. I put the answer for reference of the patterns, whether or not it does them justice is in the eye of the beholder. I don't actually expect a vote up :)

Comment: Well I like typed functional programming, not so hyped about purist FP for some of the reasons on display here. Your answer is interesting, sorry if I sounded harsh, I really like DPs so I like it when they show up on here...

Comment: @Rob I do appreciate a healthy dose of criticism, it does force you to ask questions of yourself, so thanks. BTW, as I mentioned in the answer, it is a bit clunky and I referenced the _"semicolon"_ as an alternative - that is to say that in a language like Scala, sometimes imperative style is just simpler. Now, silly, naive question, "DPs"? I am sorry for my ignorance, I don't know what that means (in this context, at least)

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? :)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple functional approach is having a case class that collects the configuration, and has methods that update their values and pass it along so it can be built at the end:

```
case class MyNettyChannel( ip: String, port: Int,
                           transportSecurity: Boolean,
                           sslContext: Option[SslContext] ) {
  def forAddress(addrIp: String, addrPort: Int) = copy(ip = addrIp, port = addrPort)
  def withTransportSecurity                     = copy(transportSecurity = true)
  def withoutTransportSecurity                  = copy(transportSecurity = false)
  def withSslContext(ctx: SslContext)           = copy(sslContext = Some(ctx))
  def build: NettyChannel = {
    /* create the actual instance using the existing builder */
  }
}

object MyNettyChannel {
  val default = MyNettyChannel("127.0.0.1", 80, false, None)
}

val nettyChannel = MyNettyChannel.default
    .forAddress(hostIp, hostPort)
    .withTransportSecurity
    .withSslContext(ctx)
    .build
```

A similar approach (without having to create the copying methods in the first place) is to use lenses, for example using the [quicklens](https://github.com/adamw/quicklens) library:

```
val nettyChannel = MyNettyChannel.default
  .modify(_.ip)               .setTo(hostIp)
  .modify(_.port)             .setTo(1234)
  .modify(_.transportSecurity).setTo(true)
  .modify(_.sslContext)       .setTo(ctx)
  .build
```

Comment: I think that the OP wanted to know how, given a 3rd party Java builder, turn the building pipeline into function composition

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I think I was unclear in my question: I don't have control over the `NettyChannel`.  That class, and the builder pattern, are provided by a 3rd party library which i'm trying to wrap in a functional way.  I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil Oh, I see. I have edited my code to show how to use the same idea with a 3rd party builder. My original `NettyChannel` class becomes just a helper container, not the actual class we are wrapping.

Comment: I don't want to sound like a downer, but this is not Builder. If you are going to provide a new implementation, please note: implementation means you cannot rewrite the whole pattern. Builder is for constructing a complex object in parts. Now if you were enforcing the fact that each unit could only yield its part, and then the final one assembled the whole from the built parts, you might have something...?