# Parameter type inference in scala

Tags: scala, types

Given a function with two type parameters, is it possible in scala to pass type parameter for a single type, for example just provide type `A` in the example as type `B` can be inferred by the compiler from function `f`.

```
def foo[A, B](f: A => B): B = {
    f(null.asInstanceOf[A])
}
```

Right now, I found only two solutions.

Solution 1 (standard usage): Call `foo` and specify both types `foo[String, Int]( e => 1)` but the definition of `Int` is redundant

Solution 2: Change the definition of the function to

```
def foo[A, B](useType: A => Unit)(f: A => B): B = {
    f(null.asInstanceOf[A])
}
```

and use it with

```
def use[T](t: T) = {}

val res: Int = foo(use[String]) { a => 1 }
```

It works, but it does not seems very beautiful to use a function to provide the type to the compiler.

Is there any way to specify just type `A` for a function taking two type parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally no, type parameters can't be partially applied in Scala. Neither in methods nor in classes. Some wrappers can be used:

```
  def myMethod[A, B]() = ???

  def myMethod1[A0, W <: Wrapper { type A = A0 }]() = ???

  trait Wrapper {
    type A
    type B
  }
```

Maybe with some path-dependent types:

```
def myMethod1[A0, W <: Wrapper { type A = A0 }](w: W)(): w.B = ???
```

And in case of not methods but classes there are approaches with type lambdas and  type members (type members can be partially applied: `Wrapper { type A = A0 }` for `trait Wrapper { type A; type B }` is an existential type like `Wrapper[A0, _]` for `trait Wrapper[A, B]`).

[Partially applying type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527684/partially-applying-type-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look deeper in this direction, and see if I can use class instead of function.